# Hide column on newpost.aspx

Tags: blog

Trying to hide the "Published" column on the `newpost.aspx` form. It's part of the content type and blog template configuration so it can't be hidden (already tried that). Using:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideFields");
function findacontrol(FieldName) {
   var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("!");
   // get all comments
   for (var i=0;i < arr.length; i++ )
   {
       // now match the field name
       if (arr[i].innerHTML.indexOf(FieldName) > 0)
       {         
           return arr[i];      
       }
   }
}

function hideFields() {
    var control = findacontrol("Published");
    control.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";
}
</script>
```

This seems to work but is still rendering the field then making it suddenly disappear. I am wondering if there is a way to just make it not render at all and completely unnoticable to the user.

Answer (score 0):

That is the nature of javascript, you're modifying what the server gives you so you see these blips. There is the possibility that you could use CSS to hide it instead, but it depends on what the markup looks like and if there is a reliable selector to hide it.

If we're talking the Published field on the content type of the item, navigate to the root of your site collection, go to Site Settings -> Site Content Types and click on Post. Click on the Published link and set the radio option to Hidden and this will remove the field from the form.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find the selector to hide the field using CSS but couldnt, unfortunately. Nothing I was able to find worked. I've already tried setting the field to 'Hidden' but it nulls out the field and the post will not render on the page. I'll keep trying with CSS or just accept it as-is with the javascript.